# Android Emulator in Android Studio does not show my app

Tags: java, android, android-emulator

I'm currently working on an android application using Android Studio. When I run my code on a Nexus 5 API 21 x86 emulator, the emulator does not show the application that I am trying to debug. I went into all applications, but I still cannot find the app I am trying to test. However, the emulator does still show an app from a previous project that I was working on. The log doesn't show any errors either when compiling the gradle and starting up the emulator.

From researching other posts, I believe it may have something to do with the version of the emulator I am running. I am not sure if that is the case and if it is how I would fix it. I have pasted a copy of my manifest below and my gradle.build. Please let me know what is wrong, this problem has been irritating me for the last several days.

```
 <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.jamescho.androidgame"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="0.5" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/bxbx_char"
        android:label="Bxbx">
        <activity
            android:name="com.Bxbx.BxbxGame.Game"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation"
            android:label="Bxbx"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
             <intent-filter>
                 <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                 <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
             </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

And the build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 17
    buildToolsVersion "19.1.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.jamescho.androidgame"
        minSdkVersion 8
        targetSdkVersion 17
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:18.+'
```

Comment: looking at the gradle info (bottom of Android Studio) does it install successfully?

Answer (score 2):

From Android Studio, go to the AVD manager (Tools>Android>AVD). Locate your virtual device, and then under actions, select the downward triangle and hit Wipe Data. This should remove the old test APK.

If the old app is still there, try just deleting the old virtual device and creating a new one. If it is still there, you are probably selecting the wrong virtual device when starting your app.

You should also try clearing the default testing device. Under Run>Edit Configurations, select the default run configuration. On the General tab, go to the bottom under Deployment Target Options and select Open Select Target Deployment Dialog, then save and try again.

Comment: I did the first part, wiping the data on the emulator. However, this does not show the new app that I am currently trying to debug. I don't see where Default run configuration or Deployment Target Options is either when going to Edit configuration

Comment: It wont be called Default; on the left pane of the configuration window the top folder should be Android App. If you maximize that, it should have the name of your app as a row. That is what will run normally, so click it and the options should appear on the the right.

Answer (score 0):

I got the Solution. 
You have to change the adb.exe file
[Download](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1W0uIRn1q5twoY5PS16QSgcbmRTz6Hmig/view?usp=sharing) the adb.exe

File Location: C:\Users[USER]\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools

**Enjoy**